# Merging rtf documents in C sharp

Tags: c#, rtf

I am using NRtfTree to merge two rtf documents. The merged document does not retain the same look as the template and it looks to be a problem to do with encoding. How do I set the encoding for NRtfTree. Or is there any other component I can use to merge two documents without using Office automation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using .Net [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx) and [Class RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(VS.71).aspx).

Create two `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` objects set the value from the first and then the second rtf file. Then create another `RichTextBox` with the two RTF documents put together.
`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.Rtf = fromNrOne + fromNrTwo`;

Comment: I want to produce the above in asp.net and not window forms, is there way of doing it in asp.net